# chrome extension. script loses functionality or how to navigate through a list of links?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Please help.
The essence of the problem:
I need to go through a list of links to pages and parse some of the data.

The main problem is that after switching to a new page, the script loses functionality. I can't figure out how I can use the extension to make the transition, spar and go to the next iteration.

Comment: How do you attach your script to the page?

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and this [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Code that you've worked on to solve the problem should include a [mcve], and be included in your question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.